# how to make continues api using URLSessionTask

Tags: swift, swift3

Hi guys below is my code im using at the moment im making a pos system and talk to a merchant and return talks to a pin pad .

the problem i have is that when i do a purchase for  the first time it works 100 percent i get a response from the service 
 . but when i do another purchase and it does the call nothing happens .

im wondering if the task inst done yet . i dont know whats going on any help

only way i can do another call is by restarting the app

```
 func pinPad(Total:Int,echoData:Int64,retrievalReferenceNumber:Int64, cardAcceptorTerminalId:Int64,cardAcceptorIdCode:Int64) -> String
{

    getdata()
    var status:String = ""

let Message =  "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>"


    var is_URL: String = "http://\(ipcon):\(portcon)/merchant/service"
    var session = URLSession.shared
    var lobj_Request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: is_URL)! as URL)
    var task: URLSessionTask? = nil
    var err: NSError?

    lobj_Request.httpMethod = "POST"
    lobj_Request.httpBody = Message.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    lobj_Request.addValue("http://\(ipcon):\(portcon)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Host")
    lobj_Request.addValue("text/xml; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    //  lobj_Request.addValue(String(count(Message)), forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
    //lobj_Request.addValue("223", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
    lobj_Request.addValue("http://\(ipcon):\(portcon)/merchant/service", forHTTPHeaderField: "SOAPAction")
    print("helo: \(lobj_Request)")

    if nil != task{
        task!.cancel()
        task = nil
    }
    let sem = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)

   task = session.dataTask(with: lobj_Request as URLRequest){ data, response, error in
        if error != nil{
            return

        }else{
            let strData = NSString(data: (data)!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) as! String
            print("Body: \(strData)")


            let xml = SWXMLHash.config {
                config in
                config.shouldProcessLazily = true
                }.parse(strData)



            if(xml["S:Envelope"]["S:Body"]["responseCode"].element?.text != nil)
            {
                status  = xml["S:Envelope"]["S:Body"]["responseCode"].element!.text
            }
            else{
                status  = xml["S:Envelope"]["S:Body"]["ns2:responseCode"].element!.text
            }
            sem.signal()

        }
        }
    task?.resume()

    sem.wait()
        session.invalidateAndCancel()
        return status

}
```

Comment: To use a semaphore to make an asynchronous task synchronous is always a bad idea because the thread is blocked. Learn to understand the asynchronous behavior and how to handle the responses properly.

Comment: i put that in after asynchronous gave me a response i handle it but then after that it still seems blocked . so was trying to only give me a response once task was done

Comment: im here to understand what i did wrong

Comment: There are a few wrong things: 1) Don't use `NS...` Foundation types if there are native Swift types, for example `URLRequest`, `String`, `URL`, `Error`. 2) In Swift there is a naming convention: variable, function, method names and enum cases start with a lowercase, `class`, `struct`,  `enum` names with a capital letter.

Comment: thanks for the tips :) any idea why this only works for one call and stops after that

Comment: As mentioned in my first comment I suppose that the semaphore blocks the thread.

Comment: it doesnt matter if i take it out or not . i take it out and it still does it :(